# Python adding Multiple check Under a function with return call

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having a below code snippet to run a quick health-check for systems and services which is working fine However, I want to include a check with elif condition for `call_function` i e `ps_rpcbind` because as of now i'm checking a `rpc` Service whether its running or not simple with a check `ps -e | grep rpc` under the `call_function` where i would like to add one of condition based on the command `rpcinfo -p` to cross validate the same.

Can I add that under `call_function`

```
import subprocess
import socket
hst_name = (socket.gethostname())
print "HostName:", hst_name
############### Function to Check the Different process & Service Status #########

def call_function(service):
   #return subprocess.call('ps -e | grep service> /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
   return subprocess.call('ps -e | grep %s > /dev/null 2>&1' % service, shell=True)
ps_ntp = call_function("ntp")
ps_nscd = call_function("nscd")
ps_mail = call_function("sendmail")
ps_postfix = call_function("qmgr")
#ps_altris = call_function("aex-plug")
ps_automnt = call_function("automount")
ps_rpcbind = call_function("rpc")

if ps_ntp == 0:
    print "Service Status:  NTP is Running on the host", hst_name
else:
   print  "Service Status:  NTP is not Running on the host", hst_name

if ps_nscd == 0:
   print "Service Status:  NSCD is Running on the host", hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status:  NSCD is not Running on the host", hst_name

if ps_rpcbind == 0:
   print "Service Status: Rpcbind is Running on the host", hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status: Rpcbind is not Running on the host", hst_name

if ps_mail == 0:
   print "Service Status:  Sendmail is Running on the host", hst_name
elif ps_postfix == 0:
   print "Service Status:  Postfix  is Running on the host", hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status:  Sendmail is not Running on the host", hst_name

if ps_automnt == 0:
   print "Service Status:  Automount is Running on the host" , hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status:  Automont is not Running on the host" , hst_name
```

### What's desired:  Based on the `rpcinfo -p`

```
if ps_rpcbind == 0:
   print "Service Status: Rpcbind is Running on the host", hst_name
elif ps_rpc == 0:
   print "Service Status: Rpcbind is Running on the host", hst_name
else:
   print "Service Status: Rpcbind is not Running on the host", hst_name
```

The command  `rpcinfo -p` returns below output.

```
   # rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
```

Please let me Know if any details required.

Comment: So what exactly you want to verify with `rpcinfo -p`, i mean as you have shown output of `rpcinfo -p` contains number of things, so what exactly are you looking for in its output ?

Comment: @Rohit, as you see its Just for check if the Service is running or not , So there are two way one way i have `ps -e| grep rpc` other way i want to include `rpcinfo -p` if it will return some value then okay otherwise it will be fail so its Just another check for the same. So evaluation Truly based on boolean values `0` and  `1` , So if  `rpcinfo -p` is not true( or doesn't not returns anything) then it will confirm the Service is failed.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

So based on your comment, i think you can do the following.

```
if ps_rpcbind == 0:
   print "Service Status: Rpcbind is Running on the host", hst_name
elif not sb.check_call('rpcinfo -p', shell=True, stdout=sb.PIPE)
    print("RPC service is running")
else:
   print "Service Status: Rpcbind is not Running on the host", hst_name
```

Please note that `0` as return code means service is running fine, but in `python` `0` is `False`, so you have to check for `not`.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your answer that is good, but i need to add this as a secondary check in the same call as i shown in the `Desired` section:  `elif ps_rpc == 0:`

Comment: That's fairly simple, just move this code in your `elif` section.